# "Date format picture ends.." error while executing a select via JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc

Working against an Oracle Database. It has a DATE typed column and the select(*simplified here for easy perusal*) statement issued via JDBC PreparedStatement is as follows:

```
select  DATE1 from TYPE_TABLE  where TYPE_TABLE.DATE1 =  ?
```

The question mark parameter value at runtime is `2018-01-31 12:50:30.0 PST`. We are setting the parameter via [setTimeStamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,%20java.sql.Timestamp)) API of the PreparedStatement class.The error that we are seeing on execution of the above select query is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before 
converting entire input string
```

I did search over SO and other sister sites of SE network and all the references I found are related to Inserting dates into the database without using proper format mask. But I didn't find anything related to select statements yet.

What could be the possible problem and the solution here?

P.S: The type of the DATE1 column is indeed of type DATE in the Oracle DB.

Edit: If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is the issue here, then what format should be used for the date value in question (i.e`2018-01-31 12:50:30.0 PST`) here?

Comment: Please, don't just describe your code. Post it.

Comment: @JBNizet we are using standard JDBC syntax...Anything in particular that you think I should be posting here?

Comment: All you think is relevant. Maybe there's a dumb mistake you've not seen in the code. If you don't show it, we can't possibly find it for you.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You have not provided any code, so we cannot decipher the exact problem. But read on for some guidance.

**Wrong data-type:** Your problem may be due to passing a moment in UTC (`java.sql.Timestamp`) for comparison to a column of type `DATE` which lacks any zone/offset (not in UTC, not in any zone/offset).

Use JDBC 4.2 or later. Pass *java.time* objects rather than strings.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDateTime.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.January , 23 ) , 
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) 
    ) 
)
```

## Oracle `DATE` type

As others noted, the `DATE` type in Oracle 11g etc. is *not* a date-only value (it has a time-of-day), and is *not* defined as such in standard SQL. It is a date-time lacking zone/offset, perhaps analogous to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type. This means such a value is *not* a specific moment, only a rough idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

For a date-time value lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, the class to use in Java is [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.January , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56

Tip: Keep in mind this is not a moment. If you want a moment, you’ll need to place this `LocalDateTime` in the context of a time zone (or offset-from-UTC). Do so by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Search Stack Overflow for more info and examples.

> We are setting the parameter via setTimeStamp API of the PreparedStatement class.

A `java.sql.Timestamp` is for a moment, a specific point on the timeline, in UTC. The equivalent type in standard SQL is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. This type is *not* appropriate for your Oracle `DATE` column – as discussed above, a Oracle `DATE` is *not* a moment.

Furthermore, you should no longer be using `java.sql.Timestamp` as it is now legacy, supplanted by the `java.time.Instant` class.

To retrieve a Oracle `DATE` value into Java:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is the issue here, then what format should be used for the date value in question (i.e2018-01-31 12:50:30.0 PST) here?

**Do not use strings at all.** Exchange *java.time* objects with Oracle database using a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects. No need for strings. No need for *java.sql* classes ever again when working with date-time values.

Avoid legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `Timestamp`. These are terribly confusing, poorly designed, and all-around troublesome. Use only *java.time* classes.

For a SQL such as:

```sql
SELECT some_date FROM some_table  where some_date =  ? ;
```

…pass your `LocalDateTime` the placeholder to your `PreparedStatement` by calling `setObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle stores date using 7 bytes. One byte each for Century, Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes and Seconds. So any string must be passed with a corresponding format string to specify how each component of that string will be parsed into the 7 byte date.

```
select DATE1 
  from TYPE_TABLE  
 where TYPE_TABLE.DATE1 = to_date('2018-01-31 12:50:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

If no format is specified, Oracle uses the default format available in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. If the default format does not match the string used, we get this error :

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before  converting entire input string
```

Comment: The JDBC should take care of the conversion. If you it manually you will risk a mismatch for different i18n environments.

Comment: @ArtBajji Do you think that the correct format was not specified while entering the dates into the DB? What should be the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the date value given in the question? i.e `2018-01-31 12:50:30.0 PST`

Comment: I am not a java pro. I am a database developer. From the database end, the format used by java and the date string are not matching to parse the seven pieces of data for date. NLS_DATE_FORMAT need not be changed. The correct format needs to be used by java.

Comment: Also note that Timestamp and Date are two different datatypes in Oracle. Date holds data upto seconds. Timestamp holds data upto 9th decimal precision of a second, costing a maximum of 11 bytes.

Comment: If the column in question is of DATE datatype, use a function that would convert your string into DATE and not TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is not SQL compliant: The data type [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) contains hours, minutes and seconds.

Documentation says:

> This datatype contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It does not have fractional seconds or a time zone.

A timestamp should only be necessary if you go down to split seconds and/or you want to store timezone information.

Can you try with [setDate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date))?

Answer (score 0):

A fair guess is that your JDBC driver will convert the Oracle Data type into a java.sql.TimeStamp or java.sql.Date type (and note that there are differences between java.util.Date and java.sql.Date, in terms of precision for example). In the case, for example, of a java.sql.Timestamp type, try specifying:

```
ret.value = java.sql.Timestamp(java.util.Date().getTime()); copy to clipboard
and see if this helps. Then you will be able to use:
ret.value = java.sql.Timestamp(system.parseDate(work.getString("yourDate"), 
    "yyyyMMddHHmmssz").getTime());
```

Comment: FYI… The `java.sql.Timestamp` & `java.sql.Date` classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes as of [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) and later.